# Check to validate a serial number

Tags: php, mysql

I am wanting to have a webpage check for a validation key that is stored in a mysql database. In the database I have 1000 serial numbers stored.

After a serial number gets validated I would like for it to return me to the page and NOT ask me for a serial number again.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php 
require 'keygen-connect.php';
$key = addslashes(htmlentities($_GET['key']));
if ($key == "") {
die("No key found");
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM `keys` WHERE key='".$key."'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Could not execute query");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
echo "Key valid";
// Setting the key activated
$query = "UPDATE `keys` SET activation='yes' WHERE `key`='".$key."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
} else {
echo "Key invalid";
}
?>
```

This is saved as a file on my server called "keygen-validate.php". This file will connect to my database and look through the serial numbers to make sure it is ok.

Where I am having trouble is the part that tells my page to run the serial number through the keygen-validation.php file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <?php 
     // what do I need to put here to have this page run this serial number
    784a97bf1955d5f7a2b9dd6c1e371e17b73c42bc
    through the keygen-validation.php file?
    ?>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

I should also add that this is meant to be something simple. I do not need the pricey options. I'm sure that folks could easily do things to circumvent my efforts but this is as much of a learning project as anything else.

Thanks

Also, it has been pointed out that I need to update to pdo ... so, yeah, I'm working on that :)

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: `key='%20or%201%3D1` this in your URL would activate all keys

Comment: Jay - You are 100% correct and I will fix that. I'm combing through some really old code updating it as I go along. Thnx for reminder.

Comment: Spark - I'm not sure I understand what you are getting at ...

Comment: Spark - Nevermind ... I looked it up and see what you were getting at

Answer (score 0):

PHP is completely unnecessary on your front-end. All you need is a `<form>` with an input for the key, which submits to your PHP script for back-end processing.

```
<form action="keygen-validate.php">
  <input type="text" name="key">
  ...
```

The submitted value will arrive in your PHP file in `$_GET['key']` as required.

Comment: The OP wants in the script head, as a means of validation I guess?

Comment: I can get this to work in a form as you suggest but what I really need is that after a number gets validated as "good" to return me to the original page and NOT ask for my serial number again.

Comment: @KulerGary That's a much larger question that the one you've asked.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using GET, you can submit the data using a form, and an action of GET.

So, for example:

`<form action="keygen-validate.php" method="get">
 Serial Number:<br />
 <input type="*inputType*" name="*key*" />
</form>`

That way, GET can retrieve your 'key' parameter.

I haven't done anything with PHP in quite some time, so someone feel free to correct / expand on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check a serial key in every page you load and the serial key is already in the URL all you need to do is `include` your script and instead of echoing the result for "invalid key" you call `exit()` or set a `header()` with proper 401 error.

Other ways to achieving what you want is to wrap your validation in a  `function` with a `$key` para meter instead of reading from `$_GET`.
Then on your page you `include` your script and call its `function` passing the `$key` value to it.